# HuggingFace - model.generate() is extremely slow when I load from checkpoint

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I'm trying to use Donut model (provided in HuggingFace library) for document classification using my custom dataset (format similar to RVL-CDIP). When I train the model and run model inference (using `model.generate()` method) in the training loop for model evaluation, it is normal (inference for each image takes about 0.2s).

However, if after training, I save the model to checkpoint using the `save_pretrained` method, and then I load the checkpoint using the `from_pretrained` method, the `model.generate()` run extremely slow (6s ~ 7s).

Here is the code I use for inference (the code for inference in the training loop is exactly the same):

```
model = VisionEncoderDecoderModel.from_pretrained(CKPT_PATH, config=config)
device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
model.to(device)

accs = []
model.eval()
for i, sample in tqdm(enumerate(val_ds), total=len(val_ds)):
    pixel_values = sample["pixel_values"]
    pixel_values = torch.unsqueeze(pixel_values, 0)
    pixel_values = pixel_values.to(device)

    start = time.time()
    task_prompt = "<s_fci>"
    decoder_input_ids = processor.tokenizer(task_prompt, add_special_tokens=False, return_tensors="pt").input_ids
    decoder_input_ids = decoder_input_ids.to(device)
    print(f"Tokenize time: {time.time() - start:.4f}s")

    start = time.time()
    outputs = model.generate(
        pixel_values,
        decoder_input_ids=decoder_input_ids,
        max_length=model.decoder.config.max_position_embeddings,
        early_stopping=True,
        pad_token_id=processor.tokenizer.pad_token_id,
        eos_token_id=processor.tokenizer.eos_token_id,
        use_cache=True,
        num_beams=1,
        bad_words_ids=[[processor.tokenizer.unk_token_id]],
        return_dict_in_generate=True,
    )
    print(f"Inference time: {time.time() - start:.4f}s")

    # turn into JSON
    start = time.time()
    seq = processor.batch_decode(outputs.sequences)[0]
    seq = seq.replace(processor.tokenizer.eos_token, "").replace(processor.tokenizer.pad_token, "")
    seq = re.sub(r"<.*?>", "", seq, count=1).strip()  # remove first task start token
    seq = processor.token2json(seq)
    if "class" not in seq.keys():
        seq["class"] = "other"
    print(f"Decoding time: {time.time() - start:.4f}s")

    gt = sample["labels"]
    score = float(seq["class"] == gt["class"])

    accs.append(score)

acc_score = np.mean(accs)

print(f"Accuracy: {acc_score * 100:.4f}%")
```

I run the model on a NVIDIA A100 40GB GPU. I used an Anaconda environment with the following requirements:

```
cudatoolkit==11.7
torch==1.13.1+cu117
torchvision==0.14.1+cu117
datasets==2.10.1
transformers==4.26.1
sentencepiece==0.1.97
onnx==1.12.0
protobuf==3.20.0
```

How to speed up Donut model inference using HuggingFace library? Thank you very much.

I haven't tried anything much other than measuring inference time when training and inference time using checkpoint.

Comment: No solution, but same problem using `from_pretrained` with a completely different type of HF model. 6s per observation is just not viable...